# How to keep focus in MessageBox

Tags: extjs, focus, messagebox, extjs3

I am using EditorGridPanel with cellEditor which acts nearly like Excel. We implemented Arrow Keys to move among rows and columns.While validating a row, if it does not match the validation rule we show a MessageBox and hope that focus does not move if it is not valid. But, after the MessageBox shows - focus moves to the next row/column. Another problem is, user have to click in the OK button of the MessageBox to remove that from screen. Can we have the focus on the invalid column editor and also focus on the MessageBox OK button - so that user can press Enter to hide the message and continue entry?

Please check our link. http://www.softworksbd.com/swazilandlmis/yyyy_stockdata.php

Answer (score 3):

Only one element can be focused, so focus should go to the message box. AFAIK enter/escape keys works out of box with message box.
You can pass callback to the messagebox. In this callback you can focus desired cell in the grid. Like this:

```
Ext.Msg.alert('Title', 'Message.', function(){ 
    this.startEditing(rowIndex, colIndex);
}.createDelegate(grid));
```

So after message box is closed, the focus will go back to the editor.